# jQuery UI Drag & Drop/Sortable Drop on empty, in Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using [jQuery UI Sortable function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder).

### Javascript

```
$('#sortablelist).sortable{
     update: function(ev, ui){...}, 
     placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
     connectWith: ".ui-sortable" 
}
```

By default, `dropOnEmpty = true` so I don't set it.

Because the list is empty, but I want to give it a 'placeholder' target in the empty list, I have given the `sortablelist` div an additional helper class to give the empty `#sortablelist` some 'surface area' to drop-into so to speak (so that you get a placeholder when you drag an element over the attached list)

### HTML

```
<div id="sortablelist" class="ui-sortable ui-sortable-helper"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.ui-sortable-helpclass {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works in *Firefox, IE, Safari,* but the placeholders will not appear (thus no area to drop to in *Google Chrome*

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I was able to solve this was by adding padding to the list.

```
#sortablelist {
  padding: 16px 21px !important;
}
```

You might not need the !important, I needed it to override some higher priority padding that I couldn't track down.

Comment: Found the problem (I'm working with jordan) - we were actually using a span instead of a div to hold the list of elements, so the padding wasn't being applied. Wrapped all of the elements in a div, added padding like you suggested, and we're good to go! +1 and thank you.

Comment: Nice, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Finally! This has been driving me crazy, but this works perfectly, I can't believe I didn't think of this.